# Mailer ruby code within a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-email, actionmailer

I have an application that uses mail to notify new users when their account had been set-up. I originally had this hardcoded, and was working well.

However, I wanted to be able to edit these emails without having to change the code. I therefore created a table that is basically an internal blog or post entry that I can used to edit those emails.

The issue I have is that if I put in ruby code inside the table entry, this just appears in the mailer as the code rather than being converted to the value of the variable.

Sorry, that's a rather confusing intro. Here is a brief summary of the code

account_mailer.rb

```
class AccountMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def account_signup(user, account, emailtext)
    @user = user
    @account = account
    @emailtext = EmailText.where(:name => "Account signup").first
    @h1 = @livetext.heading_1.html_safe
    mail :to => user.email, from: "support@mydomain.com", :subject => "Account signup"
  end

end
```

account_signup.html.erb

```
<%= @h1.html_safe %>
```

So if in @h1 I have the following text

```
Hello <%= user.first_name %>
```

Instead of seeing: Hello Michael
the mailer displays Hello <%= user.first_name %>

Is there any way to convert the content of the variable h1 to be the final values?

Michael

Comment: Are you using `user` in the view or `@user`?

Comment: You say `@h1 = @livetext.heading_1.html_safe` in the email method and then `<%= @h1.html_safe %>` in the view.  isn't this calling "html_safe" on the result of calling "html_safe" on something?  Also, where is `@livetext` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the string stored in the db as ruby code (or more accurately as embbeded ruby code). You can do this like so

```
 email_template = EmailText.where(:name => "Account signup").first
 @h1 = ERB.new(email_template.heading_1).result(binding)
```

This assumes that EmailText has an attribute `heading_1` that contains the template data

However this could be a security risk. If a user can create entries in the email text table, they can execute arbitrary ruby code on your server. My advice would be to use a different templating system like mustache to protect against such an attack.

Comment: Eval is too powerful a gun for this. I'm pretty sure it can be solved by calling `render` on correct object with correct parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that when you specify the template as a string. It doesn't matter anyway, because ERB always evaluates strings as ruby code.

Comment: Did you test this code? I have a suspicion that it won't work :)

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. Edited to match what I tried in rails console

Comment: `@email_text = ERB.new(email_template).result(binding)`. And no `eval` :)

Comment: btw, have you looked at the [source for `result`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb#L843) :) There's no escaping that eval!

Comment: At least, it's invisible :)

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed. With regards to the dangers of this usage, I totally agree. However, the contents of the objects is totally controlled by the site administrator, who understands those dangers. What it gives is the ability to change the email welcome and close messages without digging into the code and redeploying.

Answer (score -1):

@user variable is accessible in the account_signup.html.erb, so you can use is in the account_signup.html.erb

```
Hello <%= @user.first_name %>
```

It will work

Comment: You didn't understand the question.